# Using "this" instead of "scope" with AngularJS controllers and directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was recently reading John Papa's opinionated [AngularJS style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#single-responsibility) and noticed his convention on controllers:

```
/* recommended */
function Customer () {
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = {};
  vm.sendMessage = function () { };
}
```

When this is used in a controller it works just fine as you can do something like this (his example):

```
<!-- recommended -->
<div ng-controller="Customer as customer">
    {{ customer.name }}
</div>
```

However I am more curious in how it works with directives that rely on this controller. For example, using `$scope` on my controller I can do something like this:

```
testModule.directive("example", function(){
    return{
        template: "Hello {{customer}}",
        controller: "exampleCtrl"
    }
});
testModule.controller("exampleCtrl", exampleCtrl);
function exampleCtrl($scope){
    $scope.message = "Display this";
}
```

But I can't do this using `this.message`:

```
testModule.directive("example", function(){
    return{
        template: "Hello {{customer}}", //Doesn't work!
        controller: "exampleCtrl"
    }
});
testModule.controller("exampleCtrl", exampleCtrl);
function exampleCtrl(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = "Display this";
}
```

So my question is, how *would* this work in the directive? I've tried using:

```
{{customer}}
{{this.customer}}
{{exampleCtrl.customer}}
```

And none work. As you can see, I'm shooting in the dark and not really understanding the differences and how I could use `this` in Angular instead of `scope`. Also, as this isn't the convention, I haven't been able to find many resources speaking to it, since it's more a JS understanding thing than Angular.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using this style, directives should use the `controllerAs` property in their return object per the [Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) documentation.

Your directive would end up looking like:

```
testModule.directive("example", function() {
    return {
        template: "Hello {{controller.customer}}",
        controller: "exampleCtrl",
        controllerAs: "controller"
    };
});
```

Comment: Too easy, should have dug even further into the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for answering ... I will add a note to add this to my style guide. I probably shoulda had it already :)

Comment: Added this to my angularjs style guide https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide/commit/7be0536f42b06753d548138f62d4f0ce7e59a504

Comment: what about isolated scope concept?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `controller: 'exampleCtrl as controller'` also works. I should confirm but I'm too lazy this a.m.