# angularjs - ng-show does not woking

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

I use ng-show to show or hide navigator.

In index.html :

```
<div class="container" ng-show="vm.error" nav></div>
```

In app.js

```
var siteApp = angular.module('siteApp', ['ngRoute']);
siteApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/home.html'
    })
    .when('/404', {
        controller: 'ErrorController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/404.html'
    });
});
```

In HomeController.js

```
siteApp.controller('HomeController', function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.error = false;
    vm.message = "Halu home page";    
});
```

In ErrorController.js

```
siteApp.controller('ErrorController', function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.error = true;
    vm.message = "Error 404";
});
```

My navigator hides in both of pages although vm.message show true. Why ?
You can help me at : https://github.com/ryantranvn/mean

Comment: do you have an error in the console ? Did you declare your controller with the `as` syntax ?

Comment: Can you post your problem with a fiddle?

Comment: Try to display directly `{{vm.error}}` in view. For sure it is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266555/using-this-instead-of-scope-with-angularjs-controllers-and-directives) discusses regarding using `this` in place of `$scope`:

> When using this style, directives should use the controllerAs property in their return object per the Directive documentation.

A quick workaround for you would be to preface variable names with `$scope` if you want them to be available in the view:

```
siteApp.controller('HomeController', function(){
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.message = "Halu home page";    
});

<div class="container" ng-show="error" nav>{{message}}</div>
```

As to why the text was being hidden in both your test cases, the variable being used in `ng-show` was not defined.

Comment: Setting `$scope.vm.error` directly will probably crash (as vm is undefined), should set `$scope.vm = {...}` instead

Comment: @Matsemann It helps to actually test your code before posting :-)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, i tried use variable vm instead of $scope but it still not woking. My variable being used in ng-show is error, i can print it (show true/false)

Comment: I'm not using variable `vm`, so you probably didn't follow my answer then.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, i mean i tried both two ways (vm and scope). Both also does not woking. :(

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen : Can you help me ? https://github.com/ryantranvn/mean

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using "this" in the controller function, you will have to declare your Controller with "as" syntax.

If you are using routes to bind the controller, add below code in routes

```
controller: "HomeController",
controllerAs: "HomeCtrl"
```

Or if you are directly writing ng-controller in html, use below code

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl as HomeController">
   <div class="container" ng-show="HomeCtrl.error" nav></div>
</div>
```